# How to set route url

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

I have managed to deploy the app on heroku here is the 
link: [https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com](https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/movies)

when you navigate to this link : https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/ 
dispalys the whole page in general,

but when you navigate to https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/movies
you can see error: `Cannot GET /movies`

in localhost: I navigatee to routes like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/movies/movies
http://localhost:8000/movies/review
http://localhost:8000/movies/theatre
```

what do I need to change in my server.js to make it work in heroku as I want ?

```
here is my server: 
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./app/config/database');

// Connect To Database
mongoose.connect(db.database);

// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to database '+db.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Database error: '+err);
});

const app = express();

const movies = require('./app/routes/movies');

// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/movies-client/dist/movies-client')));
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/movies', movies);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/movies-client/dist/movies-client/index.html'));
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

Comment: Why are you accessing your hosted app differently than in your localhost? `/movies` vs `/movies/movies`

Comment: exactly I want to navigate through /movies/movies not /movies, I dont know what happened in my local system all works perfecly only in hosted machine , so how to change that ?

Comment: So you try to navigate to `/movies` and you get and error but you want to use `/movies/movies` which works? I don't really understand what exactly is the problem. Show us your movies router.

Comment: @VTodorov and the akward thing is changes locally on  client app side are not reflected to the hosted server :(

Comment: Of course they are not reflected. You have to commit you changes to heroku before they get reflected. Heroku is not connected to your local machine in any way.

Comment: @VTodorov https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/movies this link will give you error, the correct one should be https://damp-reef-60581.herokuapp.com/movies/movies ,  check it yourself online

Comment: @VTodorov I commit and push but no changes are reflected in my hosted for client side but for server I see changes :(

Comment: Voting to close. Unclear what you are asking. First it was a route problem now your changes are not showing....

Comment: am just curious , my point here is to solve the issue I mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what your problem is. In your `app.js` you have the following:

```
app.use('/movies', movies);
```

Then inside your `./app/routes/movies` I bet you have something like

```
router.get('/movies', function(req, res, next){ ....
```

Or something similar. The problem is that both `/movies` are added up. You are telling the server "On path `/movies` use the router `movies`. But inside the `movies` router you have another `/movies`. So if you want to have a route like this: `localhost:8000/movies` you should define your route inside `./app/routes/movies` like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){ ....
```

Because you have already told the server that you are in the `/movies` path inside your `app.js`